# Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter in module System.dll, Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, json, dll, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating Windows Phone Application 8.1 in Visual Studio 13. I do add following line of code in application to convert object into Json string.

```
private string JsonString(object obj)
{
    var javaScriptSerializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    string jsonString = javaScriptSerializer.Serialize(obj);
    return jsonString;
}
```

After adding mention line of code following dll reference need to be added in reference of solution:

```
System.Web
Syetem.Web.Extention
System.Web.ApplicationServices
```

And on build following error message thrown by compiler.

> *Cannot find type System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter in module System.dll*

I tried to add `System.ComponentModel.dll` in reference of solution but unable to add it because of error message :

> *System.ComponentModel.dll could not added, This component is already automatically referenced by build system.*

Please help me out.

**Edit**

As Stephan suggested Windows Phone 8.1 don't support `JavaScriptSerializer`, I create new method which will convert object to json string like this:

```
public string JsonString<T>(T obj)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

    MemoryStream memStrm = new MemoryStream();
    jsonSer.WriteObject(memStrm, (T)obj);
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(memStrm);
    string text = reader.ReadToEnd();

    return text;
}
```

But this method returns `string.Empty` ("") value for any object, please suggest me changes.

**EDIT 2**

Following line of code working fine for me:

```
public string JsonString<T>(T obj)
{
    DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));

    string jsonValue = string.Empty;

    using (MemoryStream memStrm = new MemoryStream())
    {
        jsonSer.WriteObject(memStrm, obj);

        byte[] jsonArray = memStrm.ToArray();

        jsonValue = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonArray, 0, jsonArray.Length);
    }

    return jsonValue;
}
```

Comment: Could you please mention how you deserialize the object from the string as well?

Comment: @Ali250 Refer my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you mixed up JavaScript with Json. The class System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer is not available for Windows Phone according to the documentation.

[JavaScriptSerializer at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Platforms: Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)

To serialize/deserialize objects to JSON you better use the DataContractJsonSerializer class. This is supported on Windows Phone as well.
[DataContractJsonSerlializer at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Platforms: Windows Phone 8.1, Windows Phone 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows 8, Windows Server 2012, Windows 7, Windows Vista SP2, Windows Server 2008 (Server Core Role not supported), Windows Server 2008 R2 (Server Core Role supported with SP1 or later; Itanium not supported)

Comment: Please can u help me out to convert object into json string by this approach? [here is some reference](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-22-Storing-and-Retrieving-Serialized-Data)

Comment: I can send you some lines of code later today. However, please also have a look at the answer of @Stígandr. In case you are ok with adding a separate package to your project then you can also use NewtonsSoft's Json Serializer. It provides you with the same functionality as the built-in serializer (probably more but I'm not sure about that).

Answer (score 3):

I am very found of [NewtonSoft's Json Serializer](http://json.codeplex.com/) aka Json.Net, and would highly recommend it, it's avaliable through [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/newtonsoft.json/).

#### Simple example

```
Product product = new Product{Name="Apple", Expiry=new DateTime(2008, 12, 28), Sizes = new string[]{"Small"}};
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
```

That's really all there is to it :) The example is taken and modified slightly from their site.

[You have a linked case here, though old.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13256495/2285592)

Cheers

Comment: This solution working fine but can we achieve same with `DataContractJsonSerializer`?

Comment: @AnkushMadankar I haven't even looked at it before, but I have alot of experience with the `DataContractSerializer`, and well it tends to break like porcelain. Json.Net is really robust.

Answer (score 0):

Following methods works for me for `Json to string` and `string to Json` Serialization:

```
/// <summary>
/// Serialize object into Json string.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of object</typeparam>
/// <param name="obj">Object which need to convert.</param>
/// <returns>Json string</returns>
public string SerializeAsJsonString<T>(T obj)
{
    var jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
    string jsonString = string.Empty;

    using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
    {
        jsonSerializer.WriteObject(memStream, obj);

        byte[] jsonArray = memStream.ToArray();

        jsonString = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(jsonArray, 0, jsonArray.Length);
    }

    return jsonString;
}

/// <summary>
/// Serialize Json string into object
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="T">Type of object</typeparam>
/// <param name="jsonString">Json string which need to parse into object</param>
/// <returns>Object of type T</returns>
public T DeserializeJsonString<T>(string jsonString)
{
    byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonString);

    using (var memStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(data))
    {
        var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T));
        return (T)serializer.ReadObject(memStream);
    }
}
```